# Run nightwatch in jessie through headless chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I have started a jessie clean vps and then I installed node.js. After that I installed nightwatch and chromedriver through npm. I made 3 files, they are nightwatch.js, nightwatch.json, and js sample testing.

Here is my nightwatch.json:

```
{
  "src_folders" : [""],
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : 
      "./node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver"
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions" : {
          "args" : ["headless", "--no-sandbox"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And for sample testing, it's just a simple testing like this:

```
var chromedriver = require('chromedriver');
module.exports = {
  before : function(done) {
    chromedriver.start();
  },
  after : function(done) {
    chromedriver.stop();
  },
  'Trial' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://www.google.com')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
      .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
      .click('button[name=btnG]')
      .pause(1000)
      .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
      .end();
  }
};
```

Here is what I got:
[image]

And everytime I run the test, it seems like the headless browser doesn't work properly. Nightwatch cannot recognize every element. When I do .assert.title('Google'), it returns 'Object not found'. I have tested it on windows and it worked smoothly. Is there something that I miss? Is it necessary to use chrome binary when I run it headlessly?

Comment: Increase the wait time of **1000 ms** within `.waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)`. But the main question is why are you waiting for the `<body>` tag? What is your _usecase_?

Comment: Thank your for your response. This is for example. In the future, I may use to wait for button, table, div, or anything else. I have waited for 1000ms which is written in the code above. But it's still the same.

Comment: Virtual _usecases_ cannot be reproduced, rather update the question with a valid _usecase_ for a well analyzed answer.

Comment: Actually that is the real example of nightwatch web itself. As shown below: http://nightwatchjs.org/guide/#using-nightwatch

Comment: Why are you using `chromedriver` in your test? Since nightwatch is starting a selenium server this is not needed.